# Degenerate berry curvature, or not(?)

Tags: quantum-mechanics, condensed-matter, solid-state-physics, crystals, berry-pancharatnam-phase

Recently I was trying to replicate some calculations concerning a particular hamiltonian, and I ran into some confusion concerning the berry curvature.

Starting from,
$$H= \frac{1}{2} \sum_k \psi_k^\dagger H \psi$$
The original haniltonian, $H$, was 2x2, and the nambu basis used was $$\psi^\dagger = (b_k^\dagger, b_{-k})$$

Now it happens that the energy spectrum here satisfied
$$E(k_x, k_y) = E(k_x + \pi, k_y+ \pi) = E(k_x+\pi, k_y-\pi)$$
Similar to, for example, $E(k)\propto (\cos(k_x)+\cos(k_y))^2$

I intended to later add an interaction proportional to $(-1)^{i_x +i_y}$, (positive on the even sublattice and negative on the odd sublattice). For this reason, I instead used the nambu spinor:
$$\psi^\dagger = (b_k^\dagger, b_{k+Q}^\dagger, b_{-k}, b_{-k+Q})$$

Where $Q=(\pi, \pi)$, and used a 4x4 matrix, $H'$, which was built simply from terms of the original hamiltonian defined at $k$ and $k + Q$, ($H(k)$ and $H(k+Q)$).

So far this is conceptually simple (I think). The original BZ was $k_x, k_y \in (-\pi, \pi)$.
My new BZ is $|k_x|+|k_y|\leq \pi$ -- half the size, but I now have two completely degerate bands.
I'm dividing the BZ by two, but doubling the number of bands.

This makes sense when thinking about the energy, but I ran into some confusion when I started thinking about the berry curvature.

In the 2x2 hamiltonian, the berry curvature calculation was very simple:
Something like
$$
i\langle u_k | \times | u_{k} \rangle
$$

But now I have collapsed this spectrum onto itself, forming two degenerate bands. Does this mean that I have to use the machinery of non abelian berry curvature? When just before, things were so simple?

Any advice that could clarify my thinking about this would be greatly appreciated. I feel that right now my understanding is very muddled.